# Is there any difference between "Platform 32-bit" or "Platform 64-bit" for Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I create Azure Functions, it will set "Platform 32-bit" for default. However I normally set ASP.NET MVC, OWIN or any other projects as 64bit.

[Platform 32-bit for default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9t6.png)

I'm wondering with **"What the difference with 32-bit or 64-bit for Azure Functions"**?

I guess this effects with NuGet Package reference and Memory allocation. However as Azure Functions can only available to assign up to 1536 MB, therefore 32-bit or 64-bit would be no effects at all.

Is there any definite reason or recommendation to set 64-bit?
Any advice will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would not suggest switching the Functions worker process to 64 bit. It will not run any better, and the memory usage will end up being higher (as it always is for 64 bit). Also, at this point Functions has only been tested in 32 bit mode so you may run into some unexpected issues in 64 bit.

---

Update (2/6/2017): see  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41978463/set-azure-function-app-on-consumption-plan-to-64-bit/41984165) for latest, as well as https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/894.

Comment: Thank you for nice advice! Understand and will stay on 32-bit. BTW, is there any plan to support 64-bit?

Comment: No plans yet. If you have a use case for why we should support it, you can add it to our feedback site - that will help us prioritize: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Not yet needed. If I met any requirement, than happy to feed back.

Comment: FYI I am using a third party DLL needing to point to 64 bit. POC works fine. It will be great if you can support 64 bit soon...:)

Comment: Just wanted to check whether it is now supported?

Comment: @RavitD This is tracked by https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/15263922-support-64-bit-functions. Can can vote it up!

Comment: This answer may not be accurate, as this issue thread on the azure repo suggests moving to 64-bit can provide a solution to a memory heap issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6095