# Set Azure Function App on Consumption Plan to 64 bit

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

The new "Consumption" tier plans that you can utilise for Functions don't allow you to change the process bitness via the Portal. Is some other way I can flip the process to 64 bits as it's required for DocDB access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set this by API. But note that it is not officially supported until you see the option show up in the portal.

Here is an easy way to do it:

- Go to https://resources.azure.com/
- Find your function app, and go under `config/web` under it in the tree
- Edit and change use32BitWorkerProcess to false

Comment: See also https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/894

Comment: Does this work for Free/Shared pricing tiers under the standard App Service Plan?

Comment: @juvchan no it does not. This setting is blocked in Free/Shared. If you try, you'll get the message *64 Bit worker processes cannot be used for the site as the plan does not allow it.*

Comment: Thanks @DavidEbbo for the clarifications and this is as expected.

Comment: It's late but You are legend @DavidEbbo

Answer (score 4):

Currently, 64-bit selection is disabled for Azure Functions (both, in consumption and app service plans). We're working on some validation to enable that, so customers requiring a 64-bit can make that change.

One thing to note is that the DocumentDB team has added 32-bit support to their latest release (1.11.3), and although we haven't upgraded to that yet (which will happen), you can reference their package directly and use their client in Functions running in 32 bit.

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41984165/1177901) also gives you a way to enable 64-bit today.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Functions consumption plan is billed based on **resource
> consumption** and **executions**. Consumption plan pricing includes a
> **monthly free grant of 1 million requests** and **400,000 GB-s of resource
> consumption per month**. Customers can also run Functions within their
> App Service plan at regular App Service plan rates.

Source: [Functions Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/)

Try to Kudu into the Function App based on the **Consumption pricing tier** App Service Plan, found out that the total disk space is 1GB, which is equivalent to the **Free** or **Shared pricing tier** of the standard App Service Plan.

> **Bitness**
>
> The Basic, Standard, and Premium tiers support 64-bit and 32-bit
> applications.

The Free and Shared plan tiers support 32-bit applications only.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-scale#bitness

The conclusion is the Consumption pricing tier App Service plan is equivalent to Free/Shared pricing tier App Service plan, which explains why it can only support 32-bit.

Comment: Note that while it is similar in some ways to Free/Shared, it also has many differences. In fact, it is possible to set it to 64 bit via API (see my answer).